# What is the difference between an offset & weight in GLM.NB package in R?

Tags: r, offset, glm

I am trying to capture the salience or dominance of a topic in a document. The measure of salience is the number of words on that topic. However, I need to control for the fact that each document has a different amount of words. (TOTAL_WORDS, mean = 2,444 words, sd= 1,379 words, min. = 561, max= 8,342 words, range = 7,781 words). If I am using a negative binomial model (glm.nb), should the Total_Words be the offset or the weight? Second, if I use the Total_Words as an offset, would it be the log of the offset as in a Poisson regression?

I have tried running models with an offset or a weight and the results I get are very different, with my coefficients being statistically significant only when I use the weights. I have looked at the documentation for this package and it says that "For a binomial GLM prior weights are used to give the number of trials when the response is the proportion of successes". Does this mean that weights would be an acceptable use in my case?

## Offset Code

```
summary(m1 <- glm.nb(Problem_Demand ~  HEALTH_CJ + offset(log(`TOTAL WORDS`))))
```

## Weights Code

```
summary(m2 <- glm.nb(Problem_Demand ~  HEALTH_CJ, weights=Dissertation_Dataset$`TOTAL WORDS`))
```

OFFSET RESULTS:

```
Call:
glm.nb(formula = Problem_Demand ~ HEALTH_CJ + 
    offset(log(`TOTAL WORDS`)), init.theta = 0.1490825725, 
    link = log)
```

Deviance Residuals:

```
    Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.55538  -1.41229  -0.45314   0.00276   1.87925
```

Coefficients:

```
                                              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                              -2.5384     0.2897  -8.762   <2e-16 

HEALTH_CJLaw Enforcement                  -0.6883     0.4796  -1.435    0.151    

HEALTH_CJOther                             0.3187     0.6031   0.529    0.597    

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.1491) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 154.04  on 149  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 151.23  on 147  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1400

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  0.1491 
          Std. Err.:  0.0183 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -1391.9620
```

WEIGHT RESULTS:

```
Call:
glm.nb(formula = Problem_Demand ~ HEALTH_CJ, 
    weights = `TOTAL WORDS`, init.theta = 0.1458893113, 
    link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-121.467   -62.381   -21.260    -3.179   108.458  

Coefficients:
                                               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                          5.297791   0.005737  923.48   <2e-16

 HEALTH_CJLaw Enforcement            -1.163340   0.009350 -124.42   <2e-16 

HEALTH_CJOther                       0.529726   0.014012   37.81   <2e-16 


(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.1459) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 391806  on 149  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 373685  on 147  degrees of freedom
AIC: 3483728

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  0.145889 
          Std. Err.:  0.000362 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -3483720.172000
```